Using promises together with a SQLite memory database
I have a shiny app that uses a SQLitebase created in R. I'm wondering if I can fetch the results somehow while working while using future_promises. Right now I'm hitting an error when I try to query the database.
library(shiny)
library(promises)
library(future)


plan(multisession)

db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "", extended_types = TRUE)
dbWriteTable(db, "iris", iris)

nameUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    
    selectInput(
      inputId = ns("rows"),
      label = "Number of rows",
      choices = c(10, 50, 100, 150),
      selected = 10
    ),
    
    actionButton(inputId = ns("start_job"),
                 label = "Start Job",
                 icon = icon("bolt")),
    
    tableOutput(ns("result_table"))
  
  )
}

nameServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      result_table <- reactiveVal(NULL)
      
      
      observeEvent(input$start_job, {
        
        print("start")

        rows <- input$rows %>% as.numeric()
        
        future_promise({
          Sys.sleep(5)
          dbSendQuery(db, "SELECT * FROM iris") %>% dbFetch() %>% head(rows)
          # iris %>% head(rows)
        }) %...>%
          result_table()
        
      })
      
      output$result_table <- renderTable({
        
        result_table()
        
      })
      
      
    }
  )
}

app <- function(){
  
  ui <- fluidPage(nameUI("app"))
  
  server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    nameServer("app")
    
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
  
  
}

app() 


Per Parallel query of SQLite database in R you need to connect to the database inside the promise. So if you save the database:
db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "db.sqlite", extended_types = TRUE)

Then this works:
future_promise({
  Sys.sleep(5)
  db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "db.sqlite", extended_types = TRUE)
  dbSendQuery(db, "SELECT * FROM iris") %>% dbFetch() %>% head(rows)
}) %...>%
  result_table()

If you're using promises, you probably want to look at ExtendedTask():
Switch the button to:
bslib::input_task_button(ns("start_job"),
             label = "Start Job",
             icon = icon("bolt"))

And in the server:
  task <- ExtendedTask$new(function(rows) {
    promises::future_promise({
        Sys.sleep(1)
        db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "db.sqlite", extended_types = TRUE)
        dbSendQuery(db, "SELECT * FROM iris") %>% dbFetch() %>% head(rows)
    }, seed = TRUE)
  }) |> bslib::bind_task_button("run")

  observeEvent(input$start_job, {
    rows <- input$rows %>% as.numeric()
    task$invoke(rows)
  })

  output$result_table <- renderTable({
    task$result()
  })

